# Search through posts and comments

Tags: c#, search, full-text-search

I have a small social feature which is part of a bigger application.

All I'm looking for is a simple search algorithm, where I can give it a string, and it will tell me yes or no. This seems like something I would have found already, but all search discusses I've seen are too in depth for this.

I know contains is too simple. I know with an input string of four words, you try them in different combinations.

Something like:

```
Bool shouldIIncludeThis(string postText) {}
```

Would be ideal

Use case:

Have a social feature with a structure similar to a blog: posts and comments.

Posts have a field called body, and so do comments.

If someone types in "outage restoration efficiency in November", I really have no clue as to how I would properly return a list of posts based on the content of the posts and its attached comments.

So I would like to loop through a collection of posts with that text in mind, never more than 300, so I'm not looking for maximum performance. Just a simple way to send in a string through the method signature, and to have that method tell me if the post or comment in question is a good match for the string provided.

I can take care of the rest.

Comment: Can you explain the use case, a bit more clearer?

Comment: Why don't you go with normal full text search of keywords and give prioritization or ranking according to some heuristics like how often the keyword occurs and is it occurring in title and post's user given keywords, like that.

Comment: By the way, you want us to suggest some data stores too for this?

Comment: That's probably a great idea, I just don't want to write it from scratch, and most examples I've seen require attaching an assembly which isn't possible. Point me to a code sample?

Comment: And combinations of words don't matter, if you go for full text search in my point of view. And you could ignore if the word under search is not noun, like that.

Comment: You could google for full text search engine for C# or solr equivalent in C# like that to get a professional engine. Moreover, it is not so difficult to write a one too.

Comment: It's sharepoint, so I have to use lists based on the install, no assemblies either as part of company policy.

Comment: What database you are using?

Comment: SharePoint with 2008 r2 datacenter. Data is in lists